# How to make python script do something if mouse is pressed?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, mouseevent

I want my python script being able to do some tasks if mouse is pressed. This is what I want to do:

```
if(mouseispressed):
  print("Pressed")
```

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far to do this, and what problems have you come across when doing so?

Comment: I have tried to use pynput do this but I cant get it to work with conditional statements like I have shown on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

```
from pynput.mouse import Listener

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    if pressed:
        print("pressed")
        
with Listener(on_click = on_click) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.